# List comprehension failing to filter list (possible date comparison issue?)

Tags: python

I have a list of dictionaries. Each dictionary contains a timestamp field. I am trying to extract only the dictionaries that have timestamps for a specified **DATE**

I am using this piece of code to extract the rows, but it is not matching any rows:

```
def extract_rows_for_date(datarows, specified_date):
    date_match_pattern = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
    extracted_timestamps = [datetime.strptime(x['ts'], date_match_pattern)
                            for x in datarows
                            if datetime.strptime(x['ts'], date_match_pattern).date() == specified_date.date()]
    # ... more logic
```

For example, if a 'row' contains a timestamp of '2012-05-14 08:24:00', then I would expect it to be pattern matched if a date of '2012-05-14' is specified as the date to match. However, at the moment,  it is not being matched using the list comprehension and date comparison logic above.

What is wrong with the snippet above?

Comment: Isolating the snippet quoted above works when passing in `datetime(2012, 5, 14)` as `specified_date` and `[{'ts': '2012-05-14 08:24:00'}]` as `datarows` so I think you need to show more of the surrounding code.  Perhaps the input when this method is called isn't what you expect?

Comment: Can you post data that you call the function with?

Comment: I spent the last hour going through the input data. It appears there is nothing wrong with the function itself - the input data (read from a database) does not actually contain the required timestamps - i.e. the test database has not been populated with sufficient fixtures data for testing.